# How to convert flash dynamic presentation to air to work in mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

can i convert my flash desktop presentation which is developed in FlashDevelope with AS3 to air to work in mobiles(Ex: Android) phones. My Presentation containes runtime dynamic data(xmls,images,swfs) loading. Is it possible?

Comment: yes of course, air extends flash functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can load static assets with no problem, but loading remote SWF containing actionscript isn't allowed on iOS and Android have restriction.

For the new version of Air you can package code in the main SWF and load SWF and linking the code. See this article for more details. [Adobe article](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/)

You can package multiple SWF in your application and load them. [Adobe article](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/)